# Casting in android programming

Tags: android

while casting objects in java this rule must apply

> Instances of classes can also be cast to instances of other classes,
>   with one restriction: The class of the object you're casting and the
>   class you're casting it to must be related by inheritance; that is,
>   you can cast an object only to an instance of its class's sub- or
>   super class-not to any random class.

I don't understand how this casting will work since i have not seen any relationship through inheritance in the android documentation:

```
     TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

the above is casting a context object to a TelephonyManager ?

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet, the casting is applied to the return value of `getSystemService()`, not a Context object. The [getSystemService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)) method's signature indicates only that it shall return an `Object`. And the documentation indicates that the exact class (a subclass of the `Object` class -- duh) depends on the argument to the method.

Answer (score 2):

The method `getSystemService()` in `Context` returns an `Object`. Since every single reference type in Java extends `Object`, it's allowed to attempt to cast it to anything.

Keep in mind that you're not casting a `Context` instance, but the result of `getSystemService`.

Comment: Thank you very much its now understandable

Answer (score 1):

It's not casting `Context`, it's casting the return value of `Context.getSystemService(String)`, which is declared to return `Object`.  The actual return type obviously has an inheritance relationship with `Object`, no matter what it is.  But if it doesn't have an inheritance relationship with `TelephonyManager`, the cast will fail at run time.

This part of the Android API is very badly designed.  They could easily have improved the type safety and avoided the ugly casting by providing methods like `Context#getTelephonyManager()`.  For that matter, they still could.

Comment: Thanks i believe so too because the method getbasectontext was confusing that's why i thought the return type was of type context